# Is it possible to use polymorphism with an abstraction layer for different widgets in Flutter?

Tags: design-patterns, dart, flutter

I have a set of around 8 widgets that all accept a single parameter of type X and display the content of type X in a different way. What I am trying to create is an abstraction layer that defines the structure of such a widget. Besides the structure, the abstraction layer would define a factory method to decide which implementation gets used based on an ID. The different implementations are all widgets that extend either Stateless- or StatefulWidget.

The abstraction layer would look like the following:

```
abstract class AbstractWidget {
final X content;

factory AbstractWidget({@required int id, @required X content}) {
  switch (id) {
    case 1:
      return Implementation1(content);
      break;
    default: return Implementation2(content);
   }
  }
 }
```

An implementation would look like the following:

```
class Implementation1 extends StatelessWidget implements AbstractWidget {
  final X content;

  Implementation1(this.content);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Display content in some type of way
  }
}
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is the following:

```
var widgetList = new List<Widget>();
for (var item in items) {
  X content = fetchContentFromAPI();
  widgetList.add(AbstractWidget(content: content, id: item.id));
}
return Column(children: widgetList);
```

This would not work because the AbstractWidget isn't technically a Widget-type, even though it can only return instances of either Stateless- or StatefulWidgets. If anyone knows a better way of implementing my structure, it would help me a lot!

Comment: Can't you just make a function that does the _switch case_, instead of using a factory constructor?

Comment: That's what I used initially but I wanted to make use of an abstraction so that in the future new implementations would have to follow the same protocol before they could get added to the list.

Comment: But that function can be used as your abstraction. If you always use that function instead of the `AbstractWidget` constructor, the behavior is about the same.

Comment: In any case, this is generally a bad idea to use advanced inheritance with widgets. Functions or composition – that's it.

Comment: It's just that the extensive switch case goes against the design patterns and principles I've been taught. This was a start to try and create a more extensible version of my code by defining a class structure for all new implementations. I don't see how the function you mentiond would define any rules to the widgets that get added to the list

Comment: Nevermind, I see now how the function would define the same functionality as the class by requiring certain parameters. However I'm still wondering if there is a better way of implementing my use case without the extensive switch case.

Comment: There's no difference between making a switch case inside a factory and inside a function besides altering or not the base class. Since the base class slot of widgets is already taken, a function is the only real alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `AbstractWidget` extend or implement `Widget`. However, I must agree with [Rémi Rousselet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8394265/r%C3%A9mi-rousselet). An abstract class should not know anything about its children (that's why it is an abstraction, anyway). I would do, instead:

```dart
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var widgetList = new List<Widget>();
    for (var item in items) {
      X content = fetchContentFromAPI();
      widgetList.add(abstractWidgetWith(content: content, id: item.id));
    }
    return Column(children: widgetList);
  }

  Widget abstractWidgetWith({@required int id, @required X content}) {
    switch (id) {
      case 1:
        return Implementation1(content);
      default:
        return Implementation2(content);
    }
  }
}

abstract class AbstractWidget {
  final X content;
  AbstractWidget(this.content);
}

class Implementation1 extends StatelessWidget implements AbstractWidget {
  final X content;

  Implementation1(this.content);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Display content in some type of way
  }
}

class Implementation2 extends StatelessWidget implements AbstractWidget {
  final X content;

  Implementation2(this.content);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Display content in some type of way
  }
}
```

I just want to make an addition about something you said:

> It's just that the extensive switch case goes against the design patterns and principles I've been taught.

The idea here is to always look for an abstraction instead of **repeating** condition structures. Notice **repeating** emphasizing. If the condition structure is used more than once, abstraction is mostly a better option. If this is not the case, you are probably overkilling the problem by creating abstraction.

Again, notice **repeating** emphasizing. You tend to need an abstraction when you have lots of condition structures, but I'll end up using **ONE** condition in the end. In other words, you can't get rid of the condition structures, you are just going to use it less.

In the context of this question, seems like you followed all the rules. This looks like a clean code to me.

Comment: That won't do. Dart classes can't extend more than one class. And `AbstractWidget` can't be represented as a mixin either because of the factory constructor.

Comment: You don't have to extend more than one class. Implementations would continue as they are: `class Implementation1 extends StatelessWidget implements AbstractWidget`.

Comment: But then it's not an abstract class, it is an interface. You can't define a method inside `AbstractWidget` that all subclasses will use.

Comment: If you implement `AbstractClass`, it'll be considered an interface. If you extend `AbstractClass`, it'll be considered an abstract class. This won't change by the time you make `AbstractClass`extend or implement `Widget`. Since OP is implementing `AbstractClass`, all subclasses are going to use its methods.

Comment: I don't know what led you to this confusion, but you can paste OP's code, make `AbstractWidget` extend or implement `Widget` and check for yourself. It works :)

Comment: I've decided to go for @HugoPassos code snippet that's based on both of your replies. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Notorius, please take a look at the addition I made at the end of the answer.